# trigger python rostest with catkin_make test

Tags: python, catkin-make, rostest, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### the goal:

I want to trigger a python unit-test trough rostest in the ros-enviroment by calling `catkin_make test` in the package-root.

the version of ros is hydro with python 2.7.3

### what works:

along the [official instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest) i wrote the test which works fine when calling it with the command `rostest jenkins_test_repro testAll.test` and the related "launch"-file as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest).

also working fine when direct executing the script...

**test-output:**

```
/home/USER/VirtEnvPython/bin/python /home/USER/sandbox/metric_tester/src/jenkins_test_repro/scripts/TestMetricStarter.py
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/USER/.ros/test_results/jenkins_test_repro/rosunit-MetricStarter.xml
test_server_feedback ... ok
test_true ... ok
-------------------------------------------------------------
SUMMARY:
 * RESULT: SUCCESS
 * TESTS: 2
 * ERRORS: 0 []
 * FAILURES: 0 []
```

**test-file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PKG = 'jenkins_test_repro'
#import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)  # This line is not needed with Catkin.

import sys
import os
import rostest
import unittest
import requests

class TestMetricStarter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_server_feedback(self):
        r = requests.get('http://SRV-ADR/MetricServer/default/index/MetricStarter' + os.getcwd())
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rostest.rosrun(PKG, 'MetricStarter', TestMetricStarter)
```

**"launch"-file:**

```
<launch>
    <test test-name="MetricStarter" pkg="jenkins_test_repro" type="TestMetricStarter.py" />
</launch>
```

### the problem:

for invoking the test-stuff trough `catkin_make test` i need add the test in the CMakeLists.txt.
i figured out 3 ways to do this and for me it's still unclear what i really need to do. for all ways i have done a clean build (removing build / devel and rebuilding catkin-workspace)

1. because of the useage of `rostest` and the analogy to the working command-line-execution

   ```
    add_rostest(test/testAll.test)
   ```

   but the test seems not to be executed:

   ```
    Running tests...
    Test project /home/USER/sandbox/metric_tester/build
        Start 1: _ctest_jenkins_test_repro_rostest_test_testAll.test
    1/1 Test #1: _ctest_jenkins_test_repro_rostest_test_testAll.test ...   Passed    1.64 sec

    100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

    Total Test time (real) =   1.65 sec
    catkin_make test  4.58s user 0.54s system 79% cpu 6.404 total
   ```

   i also tried it with

   ```
    add_rostest(scripts/TestMetricStarter.py)
   ```

   witch leads to following error

   ```
    Running tests...
    Test project /home/USER/sandbox/metric_tester/build
        Start 1: _ctest_jenkins_test_repro_rostest_scripts_TestMetricStarter.py
    1/1 Test #1: _ctest_jenkins_test_repro_rostest_scripts_TestMetricStarter.py ...***Failed    0.46 sec

    0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

    Total Test time (real) =   0.47 sec

    The following tests FAILED:
          1 - _ctest_jenkins_test_repro_rostest_scripts_TestMetricStarter.py (Failed)
    Errors while running CTest
    make: *** [test] Error 8
    Invoking "make" failed
   ```
2. just tried while it had something to do with rostest,

   ```
    add_rostest_gtest(jenkins_test_repro test/testAll.test scripts/TestMetricStarter.py)
   ```

   but seems to be c/c++ stuff due to the output and the requested linker language

   ```
    CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:jenkins_test_repro
    CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "jenkins_test_repro".
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/USER/sandbox/metric_tester/build
    make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
   ```
3. in the [official guide](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest) is a section for running [tests as part of `make tests`](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#Running_tests_as_part_of_.27make_test.27.2BAC8-CMakeLists.txt)

   this leads into a similar behaviour as in the first way

   ```
    catkin_add_nosetests(test/testAll.test)
   ```

   same as with `add_rostest(scripts/TestMetricStarter.py)`

   ```
    catkin_add_nosetests(scripts/TestMetricStarter.py)
   ```

   same as with `add_rostest(test/testAll.test)`

### and now?

so there is still the question how i have to add the test in the CMakeLists.txt... for me its unclear how to do this for a unit-test written in python. with c/cpp there are ways that are working, but for python?

due to the tool-chains on the build-farm it would be nice if there is a way to trigger the tests with `catkin_make test`. other ways which bypassing CMake are not requested by this question.

if more information is needed just ask :). i hope someone can help or give a hint to the right solution.

**Note:** i posted the same question on http://stackoverflow.com before but reconsidered that ros answers should be the better place for a relative specific question

**Update:**  just found an [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/67387/how-to-write-rostests-using-python-under-catkin/) with similar issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195462/trigger-python-rostest-with-catkin_make-test/) by [Acuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/20535/acuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described [here](http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/docs/catkin/html/howto/python_nose_configuration.html) the solution works. Still unclear is what had really had changed because `add_rostest(test/testAll.test)` was tested before (first approach)...

Just added following lines in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_rostest(test/testAll.test)
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [Acuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/20535/acuda/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1